# Asp.net Image uploading on server side using generic handler

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, generic-handler

I am trying to upload image on server side by using below code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr role="row">
      <td>
        <label runat="server"><%# Eval("Name") %></label>
        <input type="text" runat="server" style="display: none;" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label runat="server"><%# Eval("Email") %></label>
        <input type="text" runat="server" style="display: none;" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label runat="server"><%# Eval("Phone") %></label>
        <input type="text" runat="server" style="display: none;" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <img runat="server" id="ShowImage" src='<%# "~/MediaUploader/"+ Eval("Image")+".jpg" %>' alt="Image not found" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <button id="optional_upload" type="button"></button>
        <input id="f_UploadImage" style="display:none;" type="file" />
      </td>
      <td id="optional" class="text-center;">
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="optional_btn1" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClientClick="EditRow(); return false;" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="optional_lbtn1" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Button CssClass="optional_btn2" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Below is Client Side javascript:

```
function sendFile(file) {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#f_UploadImage')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'fileUploader.ashx',
    data: formData,
    success: function (status) {
        if (status != 'error') {
            var my_path = "MediaUploader/" + status;
            //$("#myUploadedImg").attr("src", my_path);
        }
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    error: function () {
        alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
    }
});
}
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#optional_upload').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#f_UploadImage').trigger('click');
});
$('#f_UploadImage').change(function () {
    alert(1);
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            sendFile(file);
        };
        img.onerror = function () {
            alert("Not a valid file:" + file.type);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
});
```

Below is my generic handler class code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
  try
  {
    string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/");
    string[] files;
    int numFiles;
    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
    numFiles = files.Length;
    numFiles = numFiles + 1;
    string str_image = "";

    foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
    {
      HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
      string fileName = file.FileName;
      string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
      {
        fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
        string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/") + str_image;
        file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
      }
    }
    context.Response.Write(str_image);
}
```

**Problem:** when I select image it successfully selected but when sendFile function runs it shows me below error:

```
error: function () {
        alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
    }
```

**Question:** How can I upload my image successfully? How I solve above error?

Comment: This appears to be an ajax error.  You should log the error being returned to narrow down the possible causes.  `error: function (err) {
        console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }`

Comment: How do you register the handler? Did you check that it is available at `localhost/fileUploader.ashx`

Comment: Its not showing any log. @devlincarnate

Comment: How to register the handler? I don't know it? Is this the issue that I am not registering it? @Andrei

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan, here is [how](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx)

Comment: what if you just `console.log(err);` in the error function?

Comment: Its not showing any error or any popup window. @devlincarnate

Comment: Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vNuwxhUjRsMUFGclI5SlU2eW8/view?usp=sharing) for another project which simply having one upload button and one input tag which is taking file from user and on this project my file uploading successfully without registering generic handler.ashx in web config file. But when I put same code in above project it shows me an error which I mention above. @Andrei

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan - it shouldn't pop up a window.  it should show the error in the console (this would be in your browser dev tool, like Firefox Firebug, or IE Developer Tools in F12)

Comment: When I run my project its shows this error in my browser console log [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vNuwxhUjRsUXI0eUk1VnR2a0k/view?usp=sharing)